# All training samples are not loading during training

Tags: python, tensorflow, nlp, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets

I'm just starting with NLP. I loaded the 'imdb_reviews' dataset from tensorflow_datasets.

There were 25000 testing samples, but when I run I only train for 782 samples. I didn't use batch_size, just loaded entire dataset at once as you can see

[image: here]

The other hyperparameters are:

```
vocab_size = 10000
input_length = 120
embedding_dims = 16
```

**Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong ?**

Answer (score 1):

By default the fit method of tf.keras.model will set the batch size to be 32.
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model

As 32*782 = 25,024 it probably just drops the last batch.

Comment: I'm learning this from courcera's "Tensorflow in practice" and for them it ran for all 25000 images at once.

Comment: It IS running for all 25000 but it's doing it in batches. You can set the batch_size to 1 and you'll see it runs 25000(ish) batches of 1 sample. Set batch_size to 2, and it'll run 12500 batches of 2 samples, etc. This is running 782 batches of 32 samples.